# Update iframe source via database

Tags: database, iframe

I'm trying to update my iframe to load a URL stored in my database. Currently I have the following:

```
<?php

$theURL = "SELECT site_url FROM pages WHERE site_id='1'";
$result = mysql_query($theURL);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>

<iframe style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" src="<?php $row ?>" width="976" height="564" frameBorder="none" id="theFrame">
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work! Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `src="<?=$row[0]?>"` ?